# spurious vertical space added between rows of first column(s) when using multicols inside a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, multicol

In the first example below I use multicols{3} within a TikZ node.
For some unknow reason there is some extra white space introduced
between the first and second lines of the first two columns.

In the second example when using multicols{3} outside a TikZ node
things works fine.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\argument#1{\mathtt{#1}}
\begin{document}
{\small
\begin{tikzpicture}
[information text/.style={rounded corners,inner sep=1ex}]
\begin{scope}
\draw
node[right,text width=9.6cm,information text,fill=red!10]
{{\bf SOLUTION TO EXERCISE 1}\\
By comparing $\argument{X}_i$ with the corresponding bounds
$\argument{A}_i$ and $\argument{B}_i$ (with $i \in [1,n]$)
we get the following nine letters $\{\ell,e,g,L,E,G\}$:
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\ell$: $\argument{A}_i<\argument{X}_i$
\item $L$   : $\argument{X}_i<\argument{B}_i$
\item $e$   : $\argument{A}_i=\argument{X}_i$
\item $E$   : $\argument{X}_i=\argument{B}_i$
\item $g$   : $\argument{A}_i>\argument{X}_i$
\item $G$   : $\argument{X}_i>\argument{B}_i$
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

The four states of the automaton have the following semantics:
};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
~\\

\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\ell$: $\argument{A}_i<\argument{X}_i$
\item $L$   : $\argument{X}_i<\argument{B}_i$
\item $e$   : $\argument{A}_i=\argument{X}_i$
\item $E$   : $\argument{X}_i=\argument{B}_i$
\item $g$   : $\argument{A}_i>\argument{X}_i$
\item $G$   : $\argument{X}_i>\argument{B}_i$
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: running the previous LaTeX program]

Comment: With TeXLive 2016 I don't see this issue. Consider upgrading at least tikz.

Comment: I think if you include the same text following the text outside of `tikzpicture` and replace `\small` with `\small\noindent` you will see that there is no issue. Your `tikxpicture` is indented and the `\noindent` resolves that.  Also you should really consider using `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` instead of resorting to a `tikzpicture` everytime you need such a box.

Comment: The other small horizontal space (`3pt` I think) is coming from the `inner sep` that is between the outside border and the left margin of the text.

Comment: Yes the problem got away by installing mactex-20161009.pkg (I was using the 2015 or 2014 version).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by OP with upgrading LaTeX distribution.

Comment: side comment: Do you know [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)? If you want to draw colored boxes, even with `multicols`, I think, it's a better tool than `TiKZ`.